# Pinpoint a particular variable error in sql 2008 script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have big SQL query like this:

```
Select Distinct [Student].[Class].roll_nbr as [PERIOD-NBR],[Student].[Class].ent_nbr as [CLASS-NBR],
  IsNull(Stuff((SELECT CAST(', ' AS Varchar(MAX)) + CAST([Student].[Subject].ent_nbr AS Varchar(MAX))
FROM [Student].[Subject]
WHERE [Student].[Subject].roll_nbr = [Student].[Class].roll_nbr
and ([Student].[Subject].class_nbr = [Student].[Class].roll_assignment_nbr
     or ([Student].[Class].roll_assignment_nbr = '0'
     and [Student].[Subject].class_nbr = [Student].[School].bus_stop) )
AND [Student].[Subject].ent_nbr <> ''
FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, ''), '')
AS [OLD-STUDENT-NBR.OLD],IsNull(Stuff((SELECT CAST(', ' AS Varchar(MAX)) + ....
```

It goes on and on and a page long query, which builds a report. The problem I am having is some variable is erring out with message:

```
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

This is very generic error does not tell me which variable. Is there any way to pinpoint which variable is erring out in sql 2008?

Comment: . . My answer is "no" and I have spent a lot of time debugging this type of problem.  Perhaps someone else will have a better answer.

Comment: Break it into pieces to isolate the error... no quick way that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out half the columns, if the error continues, comment out another half. If the error stops, it's in the section you just commented out. Rinse-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

When faced with this type of error in the past, I've narrowed it down by commenting out portions of the query, see if it executes, then uncomment portions of the query until it point right to the error.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.  However, you could try the following procedure:

1)  Identify what columns are being converted.
2)  Execute the select with half of them.  If it executes well, then the problem is in the other half.
3)  Repeat 2 (halving the number of columns) until you have come to a single candidate.

If query execution is long, keep track of all combinations tried and their result, as the problem could be affecting more than one column.  This leads to:

4)  If the problem continues, then there is a second affected column.  Discard all columns present in queries that have executed without problem, plus the incorrect one just discovered, and start again with this set on 2).

5)  Repeat until the original query (and necessary modifications) executes with no issue.